# React: How to update the DOM with API results

Tags: node.js, reactjs, parsing, axios, perspective

My goal is to take the response from the Google API perspective and display the value into a div within the DOM.

Following a tutorial : https://medium.com/swlh/combat-toxicity-online-with-the-perspective-api-and-react-f090f1727374

Form is completed and works. I can see my response in the console. I can even store the response into an object, array, or simply extract the values.

The issue is I am struggling to write the values to the DOM even though I have it saved.. 
In my class is where I handle all the API work

```
class App extends React.Component {

    handleSubmit = comment => {
      axios
        .post(PERSPECTIVE_API_URL, {
          comment: {
            text: comment
          },
          languages: ["en"],
          requestedAttributes: {
            TOXICITY: {},
            INSULT: {},
            FLIRTATION: {},
            THREAT: {}
          }
        })
        .then(res => {


          myResponse= res.data; //redundant
          apiResponse.push(myResponse);//pushed api response into an object array

        console.log(res.data); //json response
        console.log(apiResponse); 

       PrintRes(); //save the values for the API for later use
     })


        .catch(() => {
          // The perspective request failed, put some defensive logic here!
        });

    };


  render() {

      const {flirty,insulting,threatening,toxic}=this.props

      console.log(flirty); //returns  undefined, makes sense upon initialization but does not update after PrintRes()



    return (

      <div className="App">
              <h1>Please leave a comment </h1>        
        <CommentForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

When I receive a response from the API I use my own function to store the data, for use later, the intention being to write the results into a div for my page

```
export const PrintRes=() =>{
 // apiResponse.forEach(parseToxins);

// myResponse=JSON.stringify(myResponse);
for (var i = 0; i < apiResponse.length; i++) {
  a=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.FLIRTATION.summaryScore.value;
  b=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.INSULT.summaryScore.value;
  c=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.THREAT.summaryScore.value;
  d=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.TOXICITY.summaryScore.value; 
}
console.log("hell0");//did this function run

// render(){ cant enclose the return in the render()  because I get an error on the { , not sure why
return(

  <section>

       <div>
         <p>
         Your comment is:
      Flirty: {flirty}
         </p>
         </div>
         <div>
         <p>
         Your comment is:
         insulting: {insulting}
         </p>
         </div>
         <div>
         <p>
         Your comment is:
         threatening: {threatening}
         </p>
         </div>
         <div>
         <p>
         Your comment is:
         toxic: {toxic}
         </p>
         </div>

     </section>
);

}
```

Variables and imports at the top

```
import React from "react";
//needed to make a POST request to the API
import axios from "axios";
import CommentForm from "../components/CommentForm";

var myResponse;
var apiResponse= [];
let a,b,c,d;
let moods = {
  flirty: a,
  insulting:b,
  threatening:c,
  toxic:d
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for use later"? You mean you don't want to update the DOM instantly?

Comment: I just meant storing the api data as on object or variable for use later. But yes I would use that information and send it to the DOM. I realize React tends to do nearly everything in real time if you use States

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly You need to create a state where you store data from api.
States in react works like realtime stores to refresh DOM when something change. this is an example to use it

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      apiData: undefined
    };
  }

  fetchData() {
    this.setState({
      apiData: "Set result"
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { apiData } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.fetchData.bind(this)}>FetchData</button>
        <h3>Result</h3>
        <p>{apiData || "Nothing yet"}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

you can check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-cloud-l1m4x

For more info about states in react look at this:
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: This looks like it would solve my problem and I could modify my code. The only issue is how can I access specific attributes from my api in the <p> ? Do I use the map function? Or do I add more properties to the state? Referring to this part of the api that I need to display:
```
 a=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.FLIRTATION.summaryScore.value;
  b=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.INSULT.summaryScore.value;
  c=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.THREAT.summaryScore.value;
  d=apiResponse[i].attributeScores.TOXICITY.summaryScore.value;
```